# Having problems with a scrapy-splash script. I only get one result and my scraper does not parse other pages

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to parse a list from a javascript website. When I run it, it only gives me back one entry on each column and then the spider shuts down. I have already set up my middleware settings. I am not sure what is going wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class MalrusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'malrus'
    allowed_domains = ['backgroundscreeninginrussia.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.backgroundscreeninginrussia.com/publications/new-citizens-of-malta-since-january-2015-till-december-2017/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='render.html')

    def parse(self, response):
        russians = response.xpath('//table[@id="tablepress-8"]')
        for russian in russians:
            yield{'name' : russian.xpath('//*[@class="column-1"]/text()').extract_first(),
                  'source' : russian.xpath('//*[@class="column-2"]/text()').extract_first()}

        script = """function main(splash)
                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                splash:wait(0.3)
                button = splash:select("a[class=paginate_button next] a")
                splash:set_viewport_full()
                splash:wait(0.1)
                button:mouse_click()
                splash:wait(1)
                return {url = splash:url(),
                        html = splash:html()}
            end"""

        yield SplashRequest(url=response.url,
                            callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute',
                            args={'lua_source': script})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .extract_first() (now .get()) you used will always return the first result. It's not an iterator so there is no sense to call it several times. You should try the .getall() method.  That will be something like:

```
names = response.xpath('//table[@id="tablepress-8"]').xpath('//*[@class="column-1"]/text()').getall()
sources = response.xpath('//table[@id="tablepress-8"]').xpath('//*[@class="column-2"]/text()').getall()
```

Comment: Thank you. This website is scripted in a weird fashion because its Javascript but I cannot scrape all of the info from different addresses in this website.